# How can i programatically stop animating UIActivityIndicatorView using Thread

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am beginner in objective C. I have an ActivityIndicator in my project.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[loading setCenter:CGPointMake(450,400)];
[loading setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view addSubview:loading];
```

Is it possible to stopAnimating this activity indicator after some specific time **using Thread**?

Comment: Do you mean stopping `UIActivityIndicatorView` animating from another thread?

Comment: Yes....I need to set up a thread that automatically stopAnimating my activity indicator after a specific time period.

Comment: I think you can use `loading performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating)  withObject:nil afterDelay:1];`.

Comment: could you please explain this code? What is the purpose of `afterDelay:1`

Comment: It makes `loading` call method `stopAnimating` after 1 second. You can change 1 to another number for different delay. For more information, you can take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[loading setCenter:CGPointMake(450,400)];
[loading setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view addSubview:loading];
// To stop after delay of 3 
[self performSelector:@selector(StopIndicator) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

    -(void)StopIndicator
    {
    [loading stop];
    //[loading removeFromSuperview]; //uncomment if you want to remove it as well 

    }
```